# Return object in async and await in nodejs

Tags: node.js, async-await

I am new in Node.js, I have `async` method called

```
async function makeLineStringFromPoints(user) {
    ...

    for (let item of linesGeoJson) {
        saveLineIntoDb({
            'line': item,
            'date': user.date_created,
            'user_id': user.uid,
            'device_id': user.devid,
        }).then((userStored) => {
            console.log(userStored); // i received undefined  
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
    ...
}
```

in this method I have invoke other async method `saveLineIntoDb` in this method I an storing user information in database :

```
async function saveLineIntoDb(user) {
    let userStored = user;
    try {
        await db.result(pgp.helpers.insert(user, cs))
            .then(data => {
                return await (user); // return user
            });
    } catch (error) {
        logger.error('saveIntoDatabase Error:', error);
    }
}
```

Now after storing I want to return `user` in `saveLineIntoDb(user)` to `}).then((userStored)` but always I got `undefined`.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you are returning user inside the then? May be can do in this way

```
async function saveLineIntoDb(user) {
    let userStored = user;
    try {
        await db.result(pgp.helpers.insert(user, cs));

        return user; // return user

    } catch (error) {
        logger.error('saveIntoDatabase Error:', error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`saveLineIntoDb` doesn't return the result and mixes `async` and raw promises. It also prevents errors from being handled in caller function. `return await (user)` is excessive, it also won't work because it happens inside regular function.

It should be:

```
async function saveLineIntoDb(user) {
   await db.result(pgp.helpers.insert(user, cs));
   return user;
}
```

While caller function doesn't chain promises and doesn't make use of `await`. If DB queries should be performed in series, it should be:

```
async function makeLineStringFromPoints(user) {
  ...
  try {
    for (let item of linesGeoJson) {
      const userStored = await saveLineIntoDb(...);
      console.log(userStored);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

If DB queries should be performed in parallel, it should be:

```
async function makeLineStringFromPoints(user) {
  ...
  try {
    await Promise.all(linesGeoJson.map(async (item) => {
      const userStored = await saveLineIntoDb(...));
      console.log(userStored);
    }));
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: Dude `db.result` is not return user object.  http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#result    @estus

Comment: I see. It returns query string. https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.html#.insert . The rest of the answer is applicable.

Answer (score 0):

In `saveLineIntoDb` method try return result of `await`:

```
async function saveLineIntoDb(user) {
    let userStored = user;
    try {
        return await db.result(pgp.helpers.insert(user, cs))
            .then(data => {
                return await (user); // return user
            });
    } catch (error) {
        logger.error('saveIntoDatabase Error:', error);
    }
}
```

(This function, you don't need use `async/await`)

Comment: dude, In your way i still got undefined @Ｈｏｎｇａｒｃ